# Is there a way to set a flat plane at an angle to horizontal of less than 22.5 degrees, but more than 0?

Tags: building, piece-usage, disassembly

I am building an airplane with a wing dihedral (the wings angle upwards from the fuselage), but I am using parts 44302 and 44301 interlocked as designed:

[image]

Unfortunately, one click up is about 22.5 degrees, and horizontal is, of course, 0 degrees. Ideally, I need something almost exactly in the middle of the two degrees.

Are there any pieces or techniques that would let me do this?

Answer (score 6):

Using a cut-pipe into a clip-with-tube will let you build a secure and precise angle.

[image]

If you have a solid brick behind the headlight bricks you can fix the angle by cutting the pipe at the right length.

Comment: I'll look into this, though I'm worried it might be far too thick to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how sturdy your design needs to be, but using bar and clip parts could do what you want. There aren't any fixed angles when using those, so you have complete freedom, but a less rigid connection.

[image: 63868]
[image: 60478]

If strength is an issue, you could try using multiple clips or the double wide variety:

[image: 48336]
[image: 60470a]

Comment: I don't think this'll work - the wings are going to be about 7 inches long. But maybe I could stabilize it with some other pieces hidden

Answer (score 0):

You could put a sturdy (Technic?) structure inside the fuselage that provides the wing connectors with the required angles.

Comment: But are there any technic pieces that are at this angle?

Comment: I don't know of any pieces that achieve exactly such an angle, but you can build a frame that provides one. For example, you could alter this structure to result in a slightly different angle from 90°: http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=94689
I've also found this simpler, but less sturdy solution: http://www.dagsbricks.com/2013/11/lego-techniques-on-angles.html

Comment: The issue here is that the wing digital is not attached to the fuselage, but to a flat stub of a wing. So any such frame would be too thick.